# What is the standard proper way to handle HTTP communication with PHP?

Tags: php, http

I've been learning about PHP online, but couldn't find a clear complete resource on this matter.

I would like to understand how to perform the following in PHP, using the most standard and modern way:

- Read the received payload data of the request (whether POST or GET).
- Set the payload text of my response.
- Read the request headers.
- Set the response headers.
- Issue requests.

I know about globals such as `$_GET` and `$_POST`. There are also classes such as `HttpResponse` and `HttpRequest`.

It seems there are various different ways to handle HTTP communication with PHP. Please explain the standard, most common or most modern way to handle this with PHP.

Comment: Assuming you're not using a framework, you'd find those in `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_SERVER` ... request headers can be fetched using `apache_request_headers()` but the availability of that function may not be guaranteed. Setting response headers is simply `header()`.

Comment: It is much easier that what you are looking for. Typically you do not have to take care for http request details at all, since php is typically setup for that specific purpose. So you simply "output" your payload (echo, print, ...) and the http server php is embedded in takes care of the request details.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can read the request data using the super globals $_GET and/or $_POST.

The request header can be read using [getallheaders](http://php.net/manual/function.getallheaders.php).

To send a response header, use the [header](http://php.net/manual/function.header.php) function.

To send the response body, just use the common output methods like [echo](http://php.net/manual/function.echo.php) etc.

Comment: Than what are the mentioned classes used for?

Comment: This is pure procedural coding. If you don't use any framework, you must create your own classes.